# How to extract table information using BeautilSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from these kind of [pages](http://www.drexelmed.edu/Home/AboutOurFaculty/SandeepAggarwal.aspx).

I need the information contained under `Internship`, `Residency`, `Fellowship`. I can extract values from tables, but in this case I could not decide which table to use because the heading (like `Internship`) is present under a `div` tag outside the table as a simple plain text, and after that the table is present whose value I need to extract. And I have many such pages of this kind, and it is not necessary that each page has these values, like in some pages `Residency` may not be present at all. (This decreases the total number of tables in the page). One example of such page is [this](http://www.drexelmed.edu/Home/AboutOurFaculty/NabilAbaza.aspx). In this page `Internship` is not present at all.

The main problem I am facing is all the tables have the same attribute values, so I can not decide which table in to use for different pages. If any value of my interest is not present in a page, I have to return an empty string for that value.

I am using BeautifulSoup in Python. Can someone point, how could I proceed in extracting those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ids for the headings and data each have a unique value and standard suffixes. You can use that to search for the appropriate values. Here's my solution:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Insert whatever networking stuff you're doing here. I'm going to assume
# that you've already downloaded the page and assigned it to a variable 
# named 'html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
headings = ['Internship', 'Residency', 'Fellowship']
values = []
for heading in headings:
    x = soup.find('span', text=heading)
    if x:
        span_id = x.parent['id']
        table_id = span_id.replace('dnnTITLE_lblTitle', 'Display_HtmlHolder')        
        values.append(soup.find('td', attrs={'id': table_id}).text)
    else:
        values.append('')

print zip(headings, values)
```